# How to Begin Large Data Analysis in Org?

Tags: data, org

I'm a new admin and tasked with performance an analysis to address large data volumes. I'm hoping for some direction on where to begin.

How do I tell if there are current issues due to large data?
What are best places to start analyzing current org status?

Comment: Start [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/large-data-volumes/design-your-data-model). You can use the information in this trailhead and its related links to understand things like data skew and to consider how you might change the data model or processes to address such issues.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: if you have unlimited edition - [Scale Center](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.scale_center_overview.htm&type=5) can help; If you have Shield Event Monitoring, there's the analytics app that can graph performance issues

Answer (score 0):

This feels like they are setting you up to fail. You need more clarity from the business partners about what explicit issues they are experiencing that they think is a problem. Maybe you know that already and just didn't post, but that's where to start. But from what you wrote it sounds like they have this idea of what the issues are and are telling you go check it out without direction. You need to be able to reproduce whatever it is so when you investigate you know how to check to see if something changed.

Salesforce save records pretty quick if there is no logic and automation. So if the complaint was well it takes a long time to create or save a record then you could check:

- Validation rules, maybe you have a lot and it's analyzing them each time.
- Trigger Code, are there a bunch of triggers that are running every time? Is it bulk safe meaning that it's doing a query and then in a loop trying to update records?
- Flows, are there a lot of flows, or is there a flow that does a query with no filters so it returns a ton of records and then tries to work those records.

All of these are object specific so you need to find out what object is 'slow' then start looking at the automation of that object. In a full sandbox I would start by slowly turning off one automation at a time to try and isolate the issue, maybe you turn off a trigger and then it saves super quick. That would then be something to look at. Maybe there is a callout to an external API that is slow to respond. If you turn that off does it get faster?

Here's a little something from help and training about improving the performance of queries, maybe you need to index a key field or two to help speed up a query which would help performance. [Improve Performance of SOQL Queries using a Custom Index](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385213&type=1) It's hard to say that will solve the problem till you can isolate and say this specific thing is causing the records to save slowly.

I hope this helps get you on the path to success.

Comment: Thank you! It unfortunately has just been a vague task of analyze, document, and provide recommendation for addressing large data volumes and I am very new. This helps!